# Improve design of class hierarchy for a object formatter api

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

While learning object oriented design I'm judging my own design critically. This framework should be able to print objects in either XML, or JSON, I've stubbed in a basic implementation to avoid getting into details of XML and Json parser apis for now.

So I made the `Formatter` be the base class. But with my current design, all derivatives of this base class would need to know that they have to call:  `getFormattedValue()` to get output. Also I don't feel comfortable with all of those `if else` statements in the `Formatter` constructor. The clients would need to know to pass in either an "xml" or "json" in all derivatives of this class. How can I improve this design to conform to all Object oriented design Principles? Thanks in advance..

```
public class Formatter {

    private String output;

    public Formatter(Object object, String formatType){
        if(formatType.equals("xml")){
            output = getXMLFormat(object);
        } else if(formatType.equals("json")) {
            output = getJSONFormat(object);
        }
    }

    private String getXMLFormat(Object object){

        return "<title>"+object.toString()+"<title>"; // simplified
    }

    private String getJSONFormat(Object object){
        return "{"+object.toString()+"}"; // simplified
    }

   protected  String getFormattedValue(){
        return output;
    }
}
```

The derivative class:

```
public class ItemFormatter extends Formatter {

    public ItemFormatter(Employee item, String formatOutput) {
        super(item, formatOutput);
    }

    public void printItem(){
        System.out.println(getFormattedValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the var formattedValue declared?

Comment: sorry thats a typo. I fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: this question is probably a good fit for codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Split the formatting into multiple classes/interfaces and use a Factory/Factory method in order to get the appropriate formatter. It could look something like this:

```
public interface Formatter {
    String getFormattedValue();
}
```

and implement a JSonFormatter:

```
public class JSonFormatter implements Formatter {
    String getFormattedValue(Object object) {
        return "{"+object.toString()+"}";
    }
}
```

get the correct formatter:

```
public class FormatterFactory {
    public static Formatter getFormatter(String type) { // maybe use enum to decide
        if (type.equals("json") {
            return new JSonFormatter();
        } else if (type.equals("xml")) {
            return new XMLFormatter();
        }
        return new DefaultFormatter(); // returns toString for example
    }
}
```

and finally usage:

```
String formattedXML = FormatterFactory.getFormatter("xml").getFormattedValue("foobar");
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't recommend anything for `getFormattedValue()`, you can probably change the method name to make it more obvious, but that's about it.

With regards to the xml and json, you can probably use Enums.

```
public Enum EnumFormatType {
    FORMAT_XML, FORMAT_JSON;
}

public Formatter(Object object, EnumFormatType formatType) {
   if(EnumFormatType.FORMAT_XML.equals(formatType)){
    // etc...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by providing a abstract class to format.

```
abstract class Formatter {
    String format(Object o);
}
```

Then we specialize two Formatter for XML and JASON

```
class XMLFormatter extends Formatter {
    String format(Object o) {
        return "<title>"+o.toString()+"<title>";
    }
}
```

Now you just have to choose which formater you need and just call format on any of them to get the right string.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code looks more extensible.

```
public interface IFormatter 
{
    String GetFormatted(Object object);
}

public class JSonFormatter extends IFormatter 
{
    public String GetFormatted(Object object)
    {
      return "{"+object.toString()+"}";
    }
}

public class XMLFormatter extends IFormatter 
{
    public String GetFormatted(Object object)
    {
        return "<title>"+object.toString()+"<title>";
    }
}

public class ItemFormatter 
{
    public void printItem(Employee item, IFormatter formatter)
    {    
        System.out.println(formatter.GetFormatted(item));
    }
}
```

And it can be called like

```
itemFormatterInsatnce.printItem(empInstance, formatterInstance);
```

Also the formatter instance can be resolved using a formatterFactory either through code or configuration.

Comment: ItemFormatter, is this a stand alone class?

Comment: Yes..It can be a static kind of helper class also. I mean the method printItem can be accessed without creating an instance also.